# How to put propper DBFLow annotation

Tags: java, sqlite, orm, annotations, mapping

I want to insert doctor object to database, how should I put annotations for properties?
I tried to do it with te code shown below.
But i don't know how to do it on list properties `specializations` and `phoneNumbers`.

```
@Table(databaseName = WMDatabase.NAME)
public class Doctor extends BaseModel{

@Column
@PrimaryKey
@Unique(unique = true)
private String doctorId;

@Column
private FullName fullName;

@Column
private String organizationId;

@Column What shuld i put here?????
private List<Specialization> specializations;

@Column What shuld i put here?????    
private Contacts contacts;
}
```

Below are the classes I use for doctor attributes:

```
public class Contacts extends BaseModel {

private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
private String email;
private String fax;
}

public class Specialization extends BaseModel {

@Column
@PrimaryKey
@Unique(unique = true)
private String doctorId;

@Unique(unique = true)
private String specializationName;

public String getSpecializationName() {
    return specializationName;
}

public void setSpecializationName(String specializationName) {
    this.specializationName = specializationName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBFlow is a relational database system (not a mongo-type key/value store) and doesn't support lists as columns, according to the doc [here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage2/Models.md).

> List : List columns are not supported and not generally proper for a relational database. However, you can get away with a non-generic List column via a TypeConverter. But again, avoid this if you can.

The documentation on [relationships](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage2/Relationships.md) may help you refine the model to suit your needs.